# Maximum amount of equations satisfied in an overdetermined system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been searching all over the internet for a solution to my problem, but I can't find it anywhere. My problem concerns a large overdetermined linear system of equations. I want to know the maximum amount of equations I can satisfy at once. To be clear, I don't want the linear least squares solution, but a solution that satisfies the most equations (or just the amount without an explicit solution). Is there any easy way of determining this?

To be specific, I have a system of 81 equations and 27 variables. I have found an explicit solution that satisfies 65 equations. But how can I know if it's possible to satisfy more?

Also, my system is binary (mod 2). I don't think this makes it easier, it probably makes it harder, but I thought I'd mention it to be sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no upper bound on the number of equations. This is easiest to explain if the equations are homogeneous, but it can be modified for the nonhomogeneous case too: Given equations $E_1, \dots, E_m$ that the solution $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ satisfies, you can take any linear combination $c_1E_1 + \cdots + c_mE_m$, and it will also be an equation that the system satisfies.

Comment: Ah, I think I should be more clear for Sammy. I don't want the maximum amount of equations a solution to the system can satisfy. I want to know how many of the 81 equations in my system can be satisfied at once by one assignment of the variables. As I said I have found an assignment for the variables which satisfies 65 of the 81 equations, but I want to know if this is the optimal amount. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: I suspect a solution to this problem is NP-Hard.

Comment: As for SlipEternal's comment, I indeed have at least 27 independent equations. I have a program running that brute forces a solution, which is how I found the assignment which satisfies 65 equations. The program does take quite a while though. The problem is that I have other systems, with 256 or 625, or even more equations. For these it is impossible to brute force.

Comment: I just saw your NP-hard comment, and unfortunately this is what I'm suspecting too, but I hope someone might know a better solution.

Comment: Couldnt you just row reduce the system?